# Get attachment from a folder to send email, Runtime Error 13

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I want to send email with attachment(s) and encountered this Runtime Error 13 (Type mismatch) when running it.
There is only one folder and no subfolders in it. The file in the folder is in .docx format

```
Sub SendEmail_Example1()
' email processing

For i = 2 To Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

EmailItem.To = Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value
'EmailItem.CC = "hello@gmail.com"
'EmailItem.BCC = "hhhh@gmail.com"
EmailItem.Subject = "User info of " & Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value
EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi, below is your user info " & "<br>" & "User is: " & Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value & "<br>" & _
"Password is : " & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value & _
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"<br>" & "Regards," & _
"<br>" & "VT"
'Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
'---------Attachment
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim file As file
Dim folder As folder
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\duc.nguyen3-ad\Desktop\mail")
'Source = "C:\test"
For Each file In folder.Files
    If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = fso.GetBaseName(file.Name) Then

        EmailItem.Attachments.Add file.Path
        Exit For
        
    End If
Next file
    
EmailItem.Send
Next i
End Sub
```

The line where it is highlighted
`Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\duc.nguyen3-ad\Desktop\mail")`

Kindly help me to edit where it is wrong, as I do not have much knowledge with VBA. Sincerely thank you.

Comment: Maybe full referencing helps `Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject` and `Dim folder As Scripting.folder`. Ans also `Dim file As Scripting.file` of course

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub AttachFiles()

Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String, i

For i = 2 To Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .To = Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value
        .Subject = "User info of " & Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value
        .HTMLBody = "Hi, below is your user info " & "<br>" & "User is: " & Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value & "<br>" & _
        "Password is : " & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "<br>" & "Regards," & _
        "<br>" & "VT" & .HTMLBody

        strFolder = "C:\path\to\files\" ' Change to your needed folder
        strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.*")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = strFile Then
                 .Attachments.Add strFolder & strFile 'strfile is filename.filetype
                 .Display '.Send
                 Exit Do
            End If
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
        
End With
Next i
End Sub
```